# Code to disable vertical scroll bar in jScroll Pane

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

Have seen that this piece of code could solve my problems but I don't know how or where to apply it to make it work correctly

```
    JScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to hide the vertical scroll bar then use the following CSS property...

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

In your CSS (RRD.css), you have...

```
.scroll-pane
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 670px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try changing it to...

```
.scroll-pane
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 670px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**More changes**
And in your `includes/jquery.jscrollpane.css` change...

```
.jspPane
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 9660px;
}
```

to...

```
.jspPane
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5880px;
}
```

This will remove the extended scrolling that is happening. And make sure your `content-holder` width is 5880px to match the `jspPane` scrolling ...

```
<div id="content-holder"  style="width:5880px;">
```

The vertical scrollbar will not appear as long the content-holder div width is not less than the width of the content inside it. Think all your images in the content-holder div adds up to 5680px + you need to add the padding you apply as well.

Comment: By the way, the above is to be implemented in java swing. I see you have tagged the question as jquery-jscrollpane. Are you talking about [jquery jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html)?

Comment: yes I am talking about jScrollPane by Kevin Luck.  still a novice at jquery so does that go as a script on the page and do I need to call it as a function?  the page that I am working on is here http://tinyurl.com/7wrsd3k. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer. I am guessing you are trying to hide the vertical scroll bar. Please try my suggestion and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi - The scroll bar still appears that is why I was hoping to disable it. But had a look at my code with fresh eyes this morning and widen the content holder div and everything fits back on. That just means I will have to define the width of each page so it doesn't scroll to white space if there is not many images on there.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. Good to hear that you figured it out.

Comment: turns out my fix was a bad one and I still need help! I will repost but just in case you can take a look at it again - I was trying to control the width of the content-holder div so that it would fit perfectly and not have empty white space and not have the vertical scroll bar appear. Because I have expanding text panels in the scroll area that pushing the width out and if i make it too short and the vertical scroll bar appears. do you have any suggestions as it seems even though i ave tried overflow y hidden - it seems something is overriding it. here is the link http://tiny.cc/Wjzf2b Thanks

Comment: I just checked the link and I can't see the vertical scroll bar. Can you tell me when exactly it appears? And does it appear in all browsers (IE/Firefox/Chrome)?

Comment: it appears if I try make the content holder div smaller in width to cut all the white space that is after the images. It appears in all browsers that i have tested firefox, chrome  and safari and opera. don't have access to IE.

Comment: do you want me to make the content-holder div smaller so you can see it broken?

Comment: http://tiny.cc/800f2b - here is it not work and I have resized the content div to 5680px which is the size of all the images in there

Comment: @kerrysummer: have edited my answer above. I believe this should fix your issue.

Comment: First of thanks so much for taking the time to look at this. This fix works for that page but each page will be different in width depending on how many images are used.  do you think there is any way to make a different jspPane for each page.  my attempts at it didn't work so well for me!

Comment: No worries. Remove the width element from jspPane declaration. It should scale automatically to the page. Try it. You have set scroll-pane width in percentage - `.scroll-pane{ width: 100%}` which is good, so the only place you will have to change the width will be for the `<div id="content-holder style="width:xxx">` in different pages.

Comment: Whoo hoo that works - legend!  Thanks so much. You have made my day :)

Comment: hi do you think there is any chance I could get you to look at one more thing on my website as you are now familiar with the code! Have discovered that the scroll bar doesn't show in IE. Have posted the question on the forum but have no feedback so far. http://tiny.cc/04i8aw Thanks

Comment: Have answered to the question - [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729672/custom-scroll-bar-using-jscrollpane-doesnt-appear-in-ie-but-works-on-every-othe)