# custom scroll bar using jscrollpane doesn't appear in IE but works on every other browser

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

I am using jScrollPane and are just testing it in all browsers and have discovered that it doesn't work in IE. Does anyone have any suggestions. Thanks. Here is [the link](http://www.redrobyndesign.com/bbb-ie/interactive.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma after `animateScroll: true,` on your page...

change...

```
$(this).jScrollPane(
{
    showArrows: false,
    animateScroll: true,
}
```

to...

```
$(this).jScrollPane(
{
    showArrows: false,
    animateScroll: true
}
```

That should display the scroll pane in IE.